# Drupal cannot add content

Tags: html, drupal

I've just migrated my Drupal site from one host to another, and everything migrated perfectly - but I cannot "Add Content" to my site. I'm not sure if it is related to any modules, but I don't believe I've changed any modules since I've last added content.

Comment: Have you checked Status to make sure that your MySQL database is set up properly with your new host?

Comment: "Cannot", in what way? Is there an error at some point?

Comment: Yes, I made sure that everything is fine database-wise.

Comment: "Cannot" meaning that the option to Add Content has disappeared.

Comment: If Add Content has disappeared then it's likely a module issue. Make sure that your module list has the appropriate CCK modules enabled. I'd also recommend running updates.

Comment: Oh, and make sure your user account actually has the 'Add Content' module permission.

Comment: It's the admin account, and it does have that permission checked. I installed the CCK module too now, and enabled them all, but I still have no option for adding content.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login as the admin user
2. Go to http://YOURSITE/node/add
3. Choose a content type and create some content.

if that doesn't work then something in drupal core/DB is rather messed up.

Comment: That page opens, but it just says "Create Content" but with no text areas whatsoever.

Comment: On that page you should see something like this:

**Page**
A page, similar in form to a story, is a simple method.......
**Story**
A story, similar in form to a page, is ideal for creating and displaying content that informs.....

Those are links to the specific types of content you can add. If they are missing something is wrong, you could try to add a content type in that case [http://YOURSITE/admin/content/types/add](http://YOURSITE/admin/content/types/add)